# Feed Dialog - What is the Max length of 'description' parameter?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, dialog, facebook-javascript-sdk

I can't find the max lenght of description in the documentation.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Anyone knows? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Description is limited to 1000 characters, but only 300 or so (ending on a word) will be displayed. User will have to press `See more...` button to see the full description if longer than 300 characters.

Source: [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments/)

Answer (score 0):

The description of the link (appears beneath the link caption). If not specified, this field is automatically populated by information scraped from the link, typically the title of the page.

So there is no limitation in description.

Comment: This can't be right. Trial and error has shown me that descriptions over a certain length dont get attached to the post. Am I mistaken somehow?

Comment: @aking63 there is no limitation set in description on facebook developer documentation. when u put description whatever the length its just cut some part and show on feed.

Comment: Yes you're certainly right. Not sure what I was doing before but it seems to have sorted itself out. Thanks for the reply